# Cannot find a link

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, xpath, web-scraping, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to click a tab (Regulatory Regional) on a webpage: https://www5.fdic.gov/idasp/advSearchLanding.asp

However, it does not recognize the command. Here, I have attached the code.

```
import urllib2
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
import time



s1_url = 'https://www5.fdic.gov/idasp/advSearchLanding.asp'
browser.get(s1_url)
```

Problem: choose regulatory regional tab but it does not click it.

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="Banks_Regulatory_Tab"]/a').click()
```

Got an exception:

> NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="Banks_Regulatory_Tab"]/a"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Required element located inside an iframe. To be able to handle it you need to switch to that iframe:

```
browser.switch_to.frame("content")
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Regulatory Regional").click()
```

Comment: Welcome. you can [accept an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! By any chance, do you know this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070957/unable-to-locate-element-in-a-loop ? @Andersson